# How do you fill the 'o' arrowhead white?

Tags: arrows, plot

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\plot [Triangle-o,smooth,very thick,domain=11:-11]{-0.1*x+1.7};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide us with a complete Minimal Working example, i.e. with a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Provided that your code is Ti*k*Z or pgfplots, the open circle arrow head can be obtained from the `arrows.meta` library with `Circle[open]`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\draw[very thin] (-11,-11) grid (11,11);
\draw[thick] (-11,-11) rectangle (11,11);
\draw[{Triangle[]-Triangle}] (-11,0) -- (11,0);
\draw[{Triangle[]-Triangle}] (0,-11) -- (0,11);
\foreach \X in {1,...,10}
{\draw [thin] (0.1,\X) -- (-0.1,\X) node[left,font=\tiny,fill=white,inner sep=0pt]{\X};
\draw [thin] (0.1,-\X) -- (-0.1,-\X) node[left,font=\tiny,fill=white,inner sep=0pt]{-\X};
\draw [thin] (\X,0.1) -- (\X,-0.1) node[below,font=\tiny,fill=white,inner sep=0pt]{\X};
\draw [thin] (-\X,0.1) -- (-\X,-0.1) node[below,font=\tiny,fill=white,inner sep=0pt]{-\X};}
\draw[{Triangle}-{Circle[open]},very thick] plot [domain=11:-11,variable=\x]
(\x,{-0.1*\x+1.7});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]